# Why vagrant creates a new network interface from time to time

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, config, virtualbox, vagrant

From time to time I see a new "VirtualBox Host-Only Network #NUMBER" , with windows 7 network sharing center.

The important line is:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "127.0.0.3"
```

The problem with the "create a new interface every time" functionality is that vagrant uses a subroutine that delegates to virtualbox command line interface,  this command lists all avaiable networks. Last time I checked, my system listed +30 network interfaces, and vagrant up was taking more or less 10 minutes to finish.
I'm not sure it is a bug related to virtualbox, vagrant  or both.

My vagrant file (without chef configs):

```
config.vm.box = "sysfoo"
config.vm.host_name = "sysfoo.localhost"
config.hostsupdater.remove_on_suspend = true
# The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
# doesn't already exist on the user's system.
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "127.0.0.3"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8081
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3333
config.proxy.http = "http://foo:123@el_host""
config.proxy.https = "http://foo:123@el_host""
config.proxy.ftp = "ftp://foo:123@el_host"
config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you shouldn't use 127.0.0.0/8 network for *private_network*, as that's meant for loopback usage inside every machine.

A common address space for Vagrant usage is 192.168.33.x, but what ever [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) is fine as long as it doesn't collide with any other network you use. Then you don't even need port forwarding as you can access the IP directly from your host (and from other VMs on the same network).

After changing the address, you can configure `no_proxy` to something like `"localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.33.*"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thanks for the links. Using it for 30 days (more or less) and no more network adapter problems.